# Trying to generate a wave function basis set

Tags: computational-chemistry, basis-set, quantum-mechanics

For a little project I'm working on, I am trying to generate a wavefunction basis set I can use in Quantum Monte Carlo (DMC to be specific).  Preferably, it would be a linear combination of Slater determinants with a Jastrow term.

However, my problem is that I don't want a pseudo-potential or any sort of electron distribution approximation.  I want to compute the potential energy curve of a Li-C interaction (for different spacings), so it would be 3 + 12 for a total of 15 electrons (fifteen -1 charges) that interact via the BO Schrodinger equation with a positive +3 and a positive +12 charge.  Is there a tool that can do this for me?

Answer (score 1):

Not using pseudo-potentials is a great way to drive up the computational cost of a QMC enormously while not adding to the accuracy much at all.

There's a very recent paper about PPs for QMC: http://jcp.aip.org/resource/1/jcpsa6/v139/i1/p014101_s1